# How do I filter Data table Date range on window load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have following script working fine when a user click on two input which are datepicker select the date and result show correct accordingly date selected.[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bkbx2y3/180/) 
For Datepicker i am using jquery Ui library .
Now i want to run this function on window load. and set default value on `max`  and `min` variable. just forget about two inputs.i set two date default and run on window load My script is below

```
$( "#min" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'M-d-y' });
  $( "#max" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'M-d-y' });
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
        var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
        var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
        if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
        if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
        if(max == null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
        if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
    );

        $("#min").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        $("#max").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        var table = $('#html-table').DataTable();

        // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
        $('#min, #max').change(function () {
            table.draw();

        });
        });
```

i am trying to load this function on window load and set default values to `min` and `max` variables but does not show result.

```
    $( "#min" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'M-d-y' });
   $( "#max" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'M-d-y' });
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var min = $('#min').datepicker("setDate", new Date('Apr-06-17') );
    var max = $('#max').datepicker("setDate", new Date('Apr-14-17') );
    var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
    if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
    if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
    if(max == null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
    if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
    return false;
}
   );

    $("#min").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $("#max").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    var table = $('#html-table').DataTable();

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input

        table.draw();


    });
```

Comment: you can try this $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );

Comment: Where will your script get the min and max values when the page loads? If it's an AJAX call, you can just redraw the table once you have the values.